# AWS SCT error while connecting to Teradata

Tags: amazon-web-services, teradata, aws-sct

I am trying to connect AWS SCT to Teradata to migrate some tables to Redshift. However, while connecting to Teradata, I am getting the error which says -

"The specified account does not have sufficient privileges for working with the following object(s) : 
Database 'DBC' : [SELECT]

Here is the snapshot of the error (Removed some connection details) :

[image: Connection error snapshot]

What permissions should I request from the Teradata Admin to provide to the user so that I am able to access my required DB.

Comment: If it's actually complaining about a missing access right on dbc, forget it, the DBA will never grant that. It's probably some dbc views like TablesV/ColumnsV/etc. Talk to the DBA he might check the QueryLog for the actual Selects.

Answer (score 1):

User connecting to Teradata should have SELECT access on DBC to pull object metadata to be converted into Redshift DDL

Answer (score 0):

Following the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.Teradata.html), you'll need these permissions:

> SELECT ON DBC
> SELECT ON SYSUDTLIB
> SELECT ON SYSLIB
> SELECT ON <source_database>
> CREATE PROCEDURE ON <source_database>
>
> In the preceding example, replace the <source_database> placeholder with the name of the source database.